# Usage Queues to count strings

Tags: java, count, queue

I have problem with this program.
Scheme of usage, the user should input a number (how many Strings to enter), and then that number of Strings.

Example:

```
2
ASSSDDDAAA 
AAALLLOOOLLL
```

The program should then calculate the number of repeating characters in the String, and provide a suffix count.

Output (based upon the String example above):

```
AS3D3A3
A3L3O3L3
```

It should do shortcuts of inputed strings. Problem is that I shound put in queue that two strings, but when program is working I never get output from second string, moreover in first string I never get last in this example A3, it is like program dont see it (I wrote ASSSDDDAAA and I get AS3D3 idk why).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Queue<String> kolejkaWyrazow = new LinkedList<String>();
    String wyraz;

    System.out.println("Podaj liczbe ciagow liczbowych");
    int liczbaCiagowWyrazowych = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i <= liczbaCiagowWyrazowych; i++) {
        wyraz = scanner.nextLine();
        kolejkaWyrazow.add(wyraz);
    }

    MarkerCutt(kolejkaWyrazow);

}

private static void MarkerCutt(Queue<String> kolejkaWyrazow) {

    String box;
    int countRepeats;

    for(int i = 0; i <= kolejkaWyrazow.size(); i++) {
        box = kolejkaWyrazow.remove();
        countRepeats = 1;
        for(int k = 0; k < box.length(); k++) {
            if (box.charAt(k) == box.charAt(k + 1)) {
                countRepeats++;
            } else {
                System.out.print(box.charAt(k));
                if (countRepeats <= 2) {
                    System.out.print(box.charAt(k));
                    countRepeats = 1;
                }
                if (countRepeats >= 3) {
                    System.out.print(countRepeats);
                    countRepeats = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If I read this correctly, I'm surprised this doesn't give an error: `for(int k = 0; k < box.length(); k++) { if (box.charAt(k) == box.charAt(k + 1))` since it would look past the end of the String. I would think the `for` loop should be to `box.length() - 1`, but perhaps I'm not reading this correctly.

Comment: I when I add -1 error is gone but it isn't solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the OP's original code, there is an issue with the `for` loop in that the check for the next character will overrun the end of the String, resulting in a runtime error.

As to the lack of an output for the last entry in a given `String box`, it is because the output is produced while in the `for` loop of the `box.length()` itself. So, when there is a character at the end that repeats, it is never displayed. I suspect the same issue (lacking a final character) could be seen with something like `AAABBBC` that should display `A3B3C`, but would not have the last `C`.

A slightly modified algorithm would be to always display the character when it changes, and then add the count when needed.

```
private static void MarkerCutt(Queue<String> kolejkaWyrazow)
{

    // the string we are processing from the queue
    String box;

    // number of repeats for a character in the string
    int countRepeats;

    while (!kolejkaWyrazow.isEmpty()) {
        box = kolejkaWyrazow.remove();
        countRepeats = 0;
        // we hold the current character and the previous character;
        //  at entry, set the prevChar to something that cannot be matched
        char curChar, prevChar = '\0';

        // loop over the whole string; as we are not looking ahead, we
        //  use the full length of the String
        for (int k = 0; k < box.length(); k++) {

            // get the character
            curChar = box.charAt(k);

            // if we are not the same as the previous, then we
            //   may need to output the count; but output the character
            //   we just found, regardless
            if (curChar != prevChar) {
                outputCount(countRepeats);
                countRepeats = 0;
                System.out.print(curChar);
            }
            else {
                ++countRepeats;
            }
            prevChar = curChar;
        }
        // have to output the end of the string
        outputCount(countRepeats);
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private static void outputCount(int countRepeats) 
{
    if (countRepeats > 0) {
        System.out.print(countRepeats + 1);
    }
}
```

Output based upon the shown inputs (plus `AAABBBC` and 'AAABBBCC`:

```
AS3D3A3
A3L3O3L3
A3B3C
A3B3C2
```

On a broader topic, I would consider removing the actual output from the method `MarkerCutt`, and instead have a method that returned a String. It it generally a good idea to separate output from logic. So:

```
private static void MarkerCutt(Queue<String> kolejkaWyrazow)
{


    while (!kolejkaWyrazow.isEmpty()) {
        String box = kolejkaWyrazow.remove();
        String repString = changeToRepeatCount(box);
        System.out.println(repString);
    }
}

private static String changeToRepeatCount(String box)
{
    // number of repeats for a character in the string
    int countRepeats = 0;

    // We build into this structure
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // we hold the current character and the previous character;
    //  at entry, set the prevChar to something that cannot be matched
    char curChar, prevChar = '\0';

    // loop over the whole string; as we are not looking ahead, we
    //  use the full length of the String
    for (int k = 0; k < box.length(); k++) {

        // get the character
        curChar = box.charAt(k);

        // if we are not the same as the previous, then we may need
        if (curChar != prevChar) {
            outputCount(countRepeats, sb);
            countRepeats = 0;
            sb.append(curChar);
        }
        else {
            ++countRepeats;
        }
        prevChar = curChar;
    }
    // have to output the end of the string
    outputCount(countRepeats, sb);

    return sb.toString();
}

private static void outputCount(int countRepeats, StringBuilder sb) 
{
    if (countRepeats > 0) {
        sb.append(countRepeats + 1);
    }
}
```

This latter approach allows for some better/automated testing, because one can then write a driver that does something like:

```
String inp = "ASSSDDDAAA";
    String exp = "AS3D3A3";
    String res = changeToRepeatCount(inp);
    if (! exp.equals(res)) {
        System.err.println("Test Failed!");
    }
```

(or better still use JUnit or something). It will make development much easier than the need to type in a value every time to test the code. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Queue<String> kolejkaWyrazow = new LinkedList<String>();
    String wyraz;

    System.out.println("Podaj liczbe ciagow liczbowych");
    int iCount = scanner.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i <= iCount; i++) {
        wyraz = scanner.nextLine();

        if (wyraz.trim().length() > 0) {
            kolejkaWyrazow.add(wyraz);
        }
    }

    MarkerCutt(kolejkaWyrazow);
}
```

When you enter a number and press "Enter", an empty string will be added to kolejkaWyrazow, so I added "if (wyraz.trim().length() > 0)" to avoid that

Then I rewrite your MarkerCutt method, see bellow

```
private static void MarkerCutt(Queue<String> queue) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= queue.size(); i++) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String box = queue.remove();

        char c = box.charAt(0);
        int iCount = 1;

        for (int j = 1; j < box.length(); j++) {
            if (box.charAt(j) == c) {
                iCount++;
            } else {
                sb.append(c + "" + iCount);

                c = box.charAt(j);
                iCount = 1;
            }
        }

        sb.append(c + "" + iCount);

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Test :

```
Podaj liczbe ciagow liczbowych
2
ASSSDDDAAA
AAALLLOOOLLL
```

Result

```
A1S3D3A3
A3L3O3L3
```

---

If you do not want to print the count for the char which is not repeated ( count = 1 ) :

Change

```
sb.append(c + "" + iCount);
```

to

```
sb.append(c + "" + (iCount > 1 : iCount : ""));
```

Test

```
Podaj liczbe ciagow liczbowych
2
ASSSDDDAAA
AAALLLOOOLLL
```

Result :

```
AS3D3A3
A3L3O3L3
```

Comment: Fails this test case `AAABBBC` as it will output `A3B3C1`.

Comment: yes, if output do not need count for the char which is not repeated (count is 1), if (iCount > 1) can solve this, right?

Comment: I think you will need: `sb.append(c); if (iCount > 1) { sb.append(iCount); }` as you will want to add the last character, and then the count if needed. So your thought is correct, I believe.